# cant find my mistake for 'expected method body' error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting an 'expected method body' error. I can't find anything wrong. I have spent all day on this searching the internet and have adjusted this many ways based on what I have seen people say. Any insight has my thanks.

```
#import "Library.h"

@implementation Library

@synthesize list;

-(id) initList;

-(id) init{               //THE ERROR IS HERE - 'EXPECTED METHOD BODY'
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        list = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) init

{
    return [self initList];
}
```

Comment: -(id) initList{} // replace this

Comment: in the .m file method definition need to come,  r u there ?

Comment: -(id) initList; // replace this statement with this -(id) initList {}

Comment: Sorry I was watching this on the question section. It did not occur to me that I should have stayed on this page. Thank you for your help! That did fix the issue. I am very grateful to both of you who helped.

Comment: hey no need of sorry or thanks solved right that's it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two init methods and a dead `initList` which may be part of the problem. I think you meant to write:

```
#import "Library.h"

@implementation Library

@synthesize list;

-(id) initList
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        list = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) init
{
    return [self initList];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. That is what I was wanting to do. I see how I messed this up. This was perfect. Again Thank You.